# Sideband Production

Tags: distortion, harmonics, intermodulation-products

I am trying to understand exactly how sidebands are made. I've seen the math, but I'm looking for more of a component-level understanding of how they are made and what properties of the mixer determine which harmonics are produced and their amplitudes etc.

Comment: with a mixer: there's no "upper side band" component. It's all just math.

Comment: Do you have any specific circuit examples that you're confused about?  Are you speaking specifically about AM, DSB, SSB, FM or something else?  Unless you're talking about the specific non-idealities of specific circuits, it *is* just the math.

Comment: @TimWescott, I don't have any examples specifically. I just don't understand what causes sidebands. The trig identity makes sense mathematically, but I don't get how more frequencies are produced than the signal and carrier put in.

Comment: If you make the above comment part of your question, I could address it in an answer.  The *short* answer is that the *default* behavior of any physical system is to generate components at frequencies that aren't in the input.

Comment: what is a harmonic? what is a negative frequency? what is a sideband? how does a SpectrumAnalyzer work? these questions are related.

Comment: do harmonics exist? if not, how does this impact our degrees-of-freedom?

Comment: using high-frequency analog-linear-multipliers, fed by carrier and a negative frequency, you can generate the Lower Side Band. Some quadrature (vectors) components and dual mixers and then summing, all are needed. Its in the math.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input, I obviously need to go back and study more. Thanks for the leads.